# Where to place @Transactional annotation in Play

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I am trying to connect my Play application with a database, I am following controller->service->DAO layer style.

Where should the @Transactional annotation be placed. In the controller action method or can I place it in a service layer class level/method level.

I tried keeping the @Transactional annotation in one of the Service layer class's method and it has thrown runtime error.

> [RuntimeException: No EntityManager found in the context. Try to
>   annotate your action method with @play.db.jpa.Transactional]

So, do we have to use @Transactional only on top of the controller actions? I am using play 2.4.2 version. If yes, why? As I am calling my DAO's in service layer the actual database operations will begin in service layer not in controller I guess. In controller, I am just calling the service layer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would recommend not to use @Transactional because it wraps entire action in an JPA transaction. It would be more efficient to start the transaction closer to db call.

I prefer starting the transaction at service level. Also it is important to note that db call is a blocking process so it must be executed outside of default action context.

Take a look at simple DAO+Service example  https://gist.github.com/dzagorovsky/b8064c97ba647ed453ab

Also read about play thread pools here https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ThreadPools#Using-other-thread-pools

Blocking code (db calls) handling described here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaAsync

Comment: Would be nice to be able to use @Transactional annotation on other methods than actions in controllers. This `JPA.withTransaction(() -> { ...` always looks a bit ugly to me.

Comment: @Kris : as written in question "@Transactional" is not allowed to keep in other classes except controller action method in play.

Comment: @srk I just wanted to express my grief that it's not possible. It's quite useful. I'm using it with the Spring framework where it works rather well.

Comment: @Zabugor: The github link has some Java code, return promise(() -> jpaApi.withTransaction(() -> I have never seen this type of syntax. Can you explain that or direct with some links of that operator.

Comment: It is [java 8 lambda expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html#approach6). I have updated the gist with more readable version of java 6 compatible code https://gist.github.com/dzagorovsky/b8064c97ba647ed453ab#file-someservicejava567-java
Similar code with examples in java6 and java8 could be found here https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaAsync