# multiple JPA transactions (Play Framework)

Tags: jpa, playframework

I'm wondering what is the best approach for managing multiple JPA transactions for many entities (Person, School, Class, Student....)? 
- to create one GENERIC repository that will handle my CRUD
- to create multiple repositories for each Object

Answer (score 0):

As per [Domain Driven Design](http://dddcommunity.org/) by [Eric Evans](http://domainlanguage.com/about/ericevans.html) repository shouldn't care of transactions:

> Leave transaction control to the client

It means you could have multiple repositories which are called in a transactions started by some high-level service.

Pleas take a look at [gist with an example](https://gist.github.com/dzagorovsky/b8064c97ba647ed453ab) from my similar answer here [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32443893/1195766)

Here is another explanatory [article on this topic](https://programmingwithmosh.com/entity-framework/common-mistakes-with-the-repository-pattern/).